# Можно ли устанавливать Ubuntu v16 -Amd 64bit, если процессор Intel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, x86-64, intel

Можно ли устанавливать Ubuntu v16 -Amd 64bit, если процессор Intel?
Смысл ставить 32 версию для интела, если памяти на ноуте 8Гиг,архитектура 64 битная и будут ли какие-то нестыковки,если версия под AMD?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Архитектура называется `AMD64` потому, что ее разработали в AMD, а Intel - реализовала у себя поддержку. `AMD64` является дальнейшим расширением архитектуры `х86` для поддержки 64-битного набора команд и 64-битной адресации памяти.

Смело ставьте, это и есть правильное название 64 битной архитектуры для современных процессоров Intel.

Да, у Intel есть еще своя собственная архитектура `IA-64` Itanium, но она устарела и предназначалась для серверов с линейкой процессоров с одноименным названием (Itanium). `IA-64` Itanium базируется на отличной от `x86` архитектуре и программы для `х86` не совместимы с Itanium.